# Retrieve and display data from database in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to display data from different tables which are in relation with foreign keys to each other.. I wanted to display if query string `=ViewData["TagMenu"]` display "name" (which is in another table having same key) and if nameid in `ViewData["table2"]` display images which are in varbinary[max]. I created view data items by connecting to tables (`viewdata = db.table.ToArray();`). And the the images must not be in list format

```
@foreach (var t in (IEnumerable<vj.Models.catagory2>)ViewData["table2"])
{
    <p>@t.name</p>
    foreach (var v in t.nameid)
    {
        // display images in varbinary 
        //image image image....
        //image image image...
         .
         .
         .
    } 
}
```

Comment: question is not clear..can u be more descripitive?

Comment: I am new to mvc and razor and i am facing difficulty in quiring different displaying contents such as displaying particular data and images(varbineary) from database..The above question is an problem which i am working on it...I have created forigin keys tow tables like this :table1--->table2<---table3.and table1--->table3.Here symbol(--->)is a key.table2 contains images..i wanted to display all content from tables according to their relations..

Comment: are u getting the image path inside foreach loop?

Comment: No..I am facing problem in convertion

Comment: what are u getting in img variable?

Comment: I have written convertion code in controller like ths: public ActionResult imgThumbnail(int vid) {var img = db.table2.FirstOrDefault(); if (img != null &&img.imgThumbnail != null) { return File(img.imgThumbnail, "image/jpg"); } else { return File(Url.Content("~/Images/orderedList0.png"), "image/jpg"); }}  ..and written view code as                                        <img src="@Url.Action("VideoThumbnail", new { vId = v.imgID })" />                                               but displaying only 1 image having database"imgID=1" in n-loops

Comment: try without firstordefault

Comment: No..could you please tell me what else could i use instead of FirstOrDefault(); ..Also the images are in list manner(at center of html body and one below another) not side by side and next line representations..

Comment: Sir my question is that how to display modal data having two tables first table have categories and next table have sub-categories(images) in a view.such that they are ordered in category name and all sub-categories in that categories..

Comment: @YalamanchiliHari Can you incorporate your answers to people's questions back into your original question? A question should, in theory, be answerable without someone needing to read through comments first. Thanks.